# How to check last item value of list field in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hi I have a document in mongodb database. I want to check value  of last required item of list. For Example:

```
{
    "id" : "123aaaa",
    "position" : [
        {
            "centerId" : "AAAA",
            "serviceId" : "BBBB"
        },
        {
            "centerId" : "XXXX",
            "serviceId" : "EEEE"
        },

    ]
}
```

I want to desc sort "position" and check value of "centerId". If equal to "AAAA" show or not show

Comment: Could you share what you tried so far?

Comment: Please explain what "last required item" means and provide 2 input docs: one that matches the query and one that does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just convert the your position list to a Python list and do the sorting with Python's default `sorted` function.

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["db_name"]
mycol = mydb["collection_name"]


myquery = {  "id" : "123aaaa" } # This can be whatever query you want, or empty for ALL documents
mydocs = mycol.find(myquery) # Cursor to all documents

for doc in mydocs:
    doc_position = doc["position"] # This is now a list of dicts

    # You can just use Python's default "sorted" for sorting your list
    sorted_doc_position = sorted(doc_position, # The list to sort
                                key=lambda x: x["centerId"], # The key to sort it by
                                reverse=True # Descending
                                )

    if sorted_doc_position[0]["centerId"] == "AAAA": # Check if the first position is AAAA
        show = True
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but is it possible in mongodb only?

Comment: @Vagif you mean you don't want to use Python?

Comment: i want to get "serviceId" : "EEEE"